# Convert an MS Access update query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, r, ms-access, dbplyr

I am currently building a Shiny App that is based on a previous MS Access App. I need to replicate MS Access queries behind each Shiny app button in SQL Server. What is the best way to reuse the SQL syntax in MS Access in R (i.e., copy-paste the MS Access query directly in R)?

Indeed it appears that Access SQL is slightly different from SQL Server syntax and therefore I cannot simply do it using either DBI (`dbGetQuery()`, `dbExecute()`, `dbSendQuery()`) or dbplyr (`sql()`).

Here is an example with MS Access SQL syntax in R.  ("100%" is left on purpose as a table name contains that string.)

```
UPDATE [table1] 
INNER JOIN ([table2 100%] 
 INNER JOIN ([table3]
  INNER JOIN table4 
   ON ([table3].[col1] = table4.[col1]) 
   AND ([table3].col2 = table4.col2)) 
  
    ON ([table2 100%].[col1] = [table3].[col1]) 
    AND ([table2 100%].[col2] = [table3].[col2])) 

     ON [table1].col1 = [table3].col1 
SET [table2 100%].[col2] = [table3]![col2]
WHERE ((([table3].[colY])<>0) AND (([table3].[colZ])=True));
```

Resulting in the following error message in R console :

> Erreur : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'table3'.  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.

I also get : "The multi-part identifier … could not be bound in Join statements" when I tweak the query.

I set up my connection with :

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver = params.SQL.driver, 
    server = params.SQL.server, database = params.SQL.database, 
    encoding = params.SQL.encoding)
```

where **params.SQL.server = "SQL Server"**

Comment: First comment : "I cannot simply do it using either DBI" = when I copy-paste MS Access query in the statement part of that function: `DBI::dbExecute(conn = con, statement = my_query)`. It results in an error.  Second comment : yes I am trying to convert an MS Access update query in SQL Server. Naively I thought a copy-paste would work just fine. But the syntax is different between MS Access SQL and SQL server

Comment: @parfait I connected to MS Access via odbc to fetch needed tables and I wrote them onto the SQL server.  I just connected once to do that now I'm only connected to the SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `UPDATEE...FROM` translation, consider avoiding the nesting of `JOIN` as MS Access tends to do. Specifically, move all `ON` clauses right after `JOIN` clauses which should work given all tables are combined with `INNER JOIN`. In fact, you can even move `WHERE` conditions to `ON`.

Consider also table aliases for short-hand readability. Finally, usually the table colum being updated should be in `FROM` clause. Also, if `table1` and `table4` are not used for filtering, they are redundant.

```sql
UPDATE [t2]                                 -- USING ALIAS
SET [t2].[col2] = [t3].[col2]
FROM [table2 100%] t2                       -- MOVED DUE TO SET COLUMN REFERENCE

INNER JOIN [table3] t3
  ON  [t3].[col1] = [t2].[col1]
  AND [t3].[col2] = [t2].[col2] 
  AND [t3].[colY] <> 0
  AND [t3].[colZ] = 1                       -- NO True CONSTANT IN SQL SERVER

INNER JOIN [table1] t1
  ON  [t1].[col1] = [t3].[col1]   

INNER JOIN table4 t4
   ON  t4.[col1] = [t3].[col1]
   AND t4.[col2] = [t3].[col2]
```

Comment: Thank you, ordering the INNER JOIN the way you did is working. I'll also use aliases in the future

Answer (score 2):

Access has a quite curious and atypical `UPDATE` syntax with joins that allows it to update multiple tables simultaneously and merge data (add rows to tables).

SQL Server has a different syntax, where you need to be explicit about which table you're updating.

The rewrite, however, is simple:

- List the table you're updating after the `UPDATE` keyword.
- Move all the joins, including that table, to a `FROM` clause.
- Also, no exclamation marks instead of dots in SQL Server, but I recommend you avoid these in Access as well for compatibility.

```sql
UPDATE [table1] 
SET [table2 100%].[col2] = [table3].[col2]
FROM [table1] 
INNER JOIN ([table2 100%] 
 INNER JOIN ([table3]
  INNER JOIN table4 
   ON ([table3].[col1] = table4.[col1]) 
   AND ([table3].col2 = table4.col2)) 
  
    ON ([table2 100%].[col1] = [table3].[col1]) 
    AND ([table2 100%].[col2] = [table3].[col2])) 

     ON [table1].col1 = [table3].col1 
WHERE ((([table3].[colY])<>0) AND (([table3].[colZ])=True));
```

Comment: Thx for your answer that seems a little bit clearer. I just tried that out and now get the error : The multi-part identifier "[table2 100%].[col2]" could not be bound. Following this article : https://radacad.com/fixing-the-error-the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound-in-join-statements#:~:text=The%20multi%2Dpart%20identifier%20%E2%80%A6%E2%80%A6,be%20found%20in%20the%20query.  Should I write specific inner join for the 'AND' as well ?

Comment: @Cam11 That error regarding the multi-part identifier usually means you either misspelled a table or column name. Check your names thoroughly, a percentage sign should be allowed in a table name but that might be bothering you.

Comment: This multi-part identifier error might be due to the nesting of `JOIN`s.